# How does Flask url_for work?

Tags: python, flask

```
flask.url_for(endpoint, **values)
```

The `endpoint` thing seems like magic to me. It behaves these ways:

1. in a single file, a decorated method `dothat` can be acquired by `url_for('dothat')`
2. with [packaging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/), `views.dothat` can be acquired by `url_for('dothat')`, when I was expecting that I must provide the **fully qualified** method name, as in `url_for('myapp.views.dothat')`

So if it's not the fully qualified method name, what does Flask take in as endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask does *not* use the module name for the endpoint. It simply defaults to the function name.

If you register two different functions with the same name (say, in two different modules), an `AssertionError` exception is raised:

```
raise AssertionError('View function mapping is overwriting an '
                     'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
```

You can specify an explicit endpoint name in such cases:

```
@app.route('/', endpoint='alt_homepage')
def homepage():
    pass
```

See the [`@Flask.route()` documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.route):

> **endpoint** – the endpoint for the registered URL rule. Flask itself assumes the name of the view function as endpoint

When you register a view (with the `@app.route()` decorator), the endpoint name is determined (unless you set one explicitly) and stored with the route registration. `url_for()` uses the route registration to find all routes registered against that name and finds the one best fitting the parameters you also passed to `url_for()`.

Comment: what happens when two functions have the same name, but are in different modules?

Comment: @aitchnyu: then you'll need to give one an explicit `endpoint` value.